# JQuery hover multiple elements one function

Tags: jquery, hover

I have three divs with hidden inner divs, when you rollover over each div its inner div should display and when you rollout it hides again.

for example, I rollover div1, div1 inner appears, I rollout, div1 inner disappears.

However when I move my mouse from div1 directly over div2, both are treated as rollout, eg div1 inner disappears (as it should), div2 inner appears(as it should) but then instantly disappears with div1 inner.

Apart from writing separate functions for div1 2 and 3 I'm not sure what to do, any help much appreciated!!

jsfiddle.net/user1688604/UZpEH/3

```
var box = $("#box1,#box2,#box3");
var inner = $(".item");


$(box).hover(function() {
    $(this).find(inner).stop(true,true).css({"left":"20px"}).animate({"top":"-10px", "opacity": "1"},400);

}, function() {
    $(this).find(inner).stop(true,true).animate({"top":"-20px", "opacity": "0"},400, function() {
        $(inner).css({"left":"-9999px", "top":"0"});
        });
});



<div id="box1">
<div class="item"></div>
</div>

#box1, #box2, #box3 {
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 20px;
            position: relative;
            }


            .item {
                width: 151px;
                height: 49px;
                padding: 5px 10px 0;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: -9999px;
                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a class to the box divs (same class for each)

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".box").hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".item").stop(true,true).css({"left":"20px"}).animate({"top":"-10px", "opacity": "1"},400);
},function(){
   $(this).find(".item").animate({"top":"-20px", "opacity": "0"},400, function() {
       $(this).css({"left":"-9999px", "top":"0"});
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/user1688604/UZpEH/3/  It is still happening, I think maybe the rollout animation doesn't have time to finish if you move to the next box too fast?

Comment: Fixed it with my code..http://jsfiddle.net/UZpEH/5/  You can't declare $(".item") outside of the hover because it will pull in all the divs with class item and run the animation on all of them.

Comment: I also recommend hoverIntent, when doing hover functions. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

On Whichever div or any fields , you wanna provide hover function just call then with same class name ,then trigger your function by referring that class name.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have added a jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/user1688604/UZpEH/3 It is still happening, I think maybe the rollout animation doesn't have time to finish if you move to the next box too fast?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below... it will help you..

Keep Same class name for all the DIV.. and try the below..

Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/96/

**HTML :**

```
<div class="divBox">
    Show Div1
<div class="item">
Div 1    
</div>
</div>

<div class="divBox">
    Show Div 2
<div class="item">
    Div 2

</div>
</div>

<div class="divBox">
    Show Div 3
<div class="item">    
    Div 3
</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$('.item').hide(); 
$('.divBox').hover(function() { 
    $(this).children('.item').show();     
}, function() { 
    $(this).children('.item').hide(); 
});
```